# SQL query: How to select the first 100000-200000 rows in a huge table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know the normal way should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY date
OFFSET 100000 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 100000 ROWS
```

However, when mytable has 80 Million rows, the "ORDER BY" command will takes a long time to run. To me, the order doesn't matter, I just want to download 100,000 rows of data one at each time. Is there any good way to achieve it?

Comment: Include [with (nolock)] in your select query so, you stand the risk of reading an uncommitted row that is subsequently rolled back.

Comment: @jzoler if you're going to recommend `NOLOCK` you should include all the caveats that go with it; and how the data can be wrong.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzMaN-IX7wQ

Comment: Remove the `OFFSET` and `ORDER BY` if you don't care about the order.

Answer (score 4):

The `order by` only takes a long time because you use a column without an index on it. Use an indexed column like an `id` column in your `order by`.

Or add an index on  `date`

Answer (score 0):

If the order doesn't matter, just don't use it. But the correct point is to follow @juergen instructions. Try to order always on indexed columns.
I'm not sure if you fetch 100k lines at once, the system will load 100k rows to memory.
But when you process this, the loop will work over the 100k rows and will end.

¿Could you explain why order does not matter to you?
Without that, you can get repeated rows within different fetches.

If you use order, you ensure to not get repeated rows.

If th query is slow, create an index.
In this kind of select, I'm not sure if pruning would help, as you have no where clause.

Comment: But the order does matter. There's no garantuee you'll get a particular order back as data keeps mutating. Thus 'pages' of data might be shuffled around while new data inserted. Right?

Comment: The comment of the questions says explicitly: "To me, the order doesn't matter, I just want to download 100,000 rows"
I understand, in this case, the order is not important.

Comment: the order might not matter. But if you use `OFFSET` you'll likely want to retrieve 'pages' of rows. In that case it does matter as you don't want the pages to be shuffled around while you are moving through the data. So order might not matter, but you want to use `ORDER BY` with `OFFSET`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Maybe the question confusing. Has no much sense to not order and to retrieve rows like that, but we don't know the purposes of that loop.